# how to use ViewData in a declarative view

Tags: sapui5

I like the idea of using viewdata to inject user context into a view without using models.

The data can be passed into the constructor

```
sap.ui.view({
  viewName: "myApp.employeeAccess",
  type: sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.<type>,
  viewData: userData
});
```

and in a jsView the values can be used dynamically

```
createContent: function(oController) {
  if (this.getViewData().param1 === 'A') {
  ...
```

Is there a way of accessing viewData statically in a HTML or XML view?

not sure of the syntax but was thinking it may be like

```
<Text
    text="{path : '{viewData.param1}',
           formatter : 'util.Formatter.headerText'}">
</Text>
```

EDIT: changed the example to show a generic param as opposed to something looking like business data

Comment: Sounds slightly leaky to me. At least philosophically, would you consider this to break or enhance the MV* concept?

Comment: the example was very misleading so changed, based on the value of a URL parameter show the required header text

Comment: For those interested an example - in my scenario persg is a url param sent from another application https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/resources/sap/ushell/components/factsheet/views/ThingViewer-dbg.view.js

Comment: So can viewdata be compared as parameters to the constructor of the view?

Comment: @dparnas yes, I think view paramaters property bag is a better desc than "user specific" or "user context" data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of your edited question (showing different texts depending on a URL parameter), I'd suggest two things:

- models should be the mechanism for making data available to views
- URL value based decisions should be handled via [routing](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.routing.html)

For various levels of strength of "should", of course.

Comment: From the doco  "The view data oView.viewData can hold user specific data. This data is available during the whole lifecycle of the view and the controller"  this would suggest an alternative to models   http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2013/12/18/how-to-improve-the-testability-of-a-sapui5-app suggests it improves the testability

Comment: the second example is probably as bad as the first

Answer (score 2):

first of all you would need to create a model and attach it to the view you want to bind data to or register it globally. Check my answer on Data Binding here:
[SAPUI5-How to bind data to sap.ui.layout.form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21314079/sapui5-how-to-bind-data-to-sap-ui-layout-form/21319958#21319958)

Concerning the use of HTMLView and XMLView check my general answer on Declarative Support here: [Declarative support questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20836253/declarative-support-questions/21320407#21320407)

GL
Chris

Answer (score 1):

You can overload every managed ui5 Object like the way you did.

But in your case you should use datamodels. Check the docu: https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/GettingStarted.html

Comment: Hi Manuel, I like your answer, in my case ManagedObject constructor : function(sId, mSettings, oScope) { i didnt overload see sap.ui.core.mvc.View oViewData = mSettings.viewData, how would you overload the constructor?

Comment: it's not directly an overload. you can set new properties inside the settings. and ui5 will generate automatically new getters and setters for this property. as exammple: var btn = new sap.m.Button({foo: 'bar'}); btn.getFoo();

Comment: thanks, as DJ says slightly leaky but interesting to know, any side effects if you introduce properties not in the metadata?

Comment: if you are settings properties that are already exists in this object, you'll overwrite it. but i think there is no other sideeffect.

Comment: i tried your example var btn = new sap.m.Button("btn',{foo: 'bar'}); btn.getFoo(); doesnt work, looks like mutators are only created if mValidKeys['foo'] exists in metadata, tried with view also and the same

Comment: that is strange. i used this before. i am sure it works. let me check this.

Comment: yes, you're right it is not working. and now i am a little bit confused and very sorry. i will again analyse this tonight at home.